# How to pass in multiple input arguments to Popen()?

Tags: python

I am writing a script which installs a command line interface for a user.

```
proc = Popen("sudo -S apt-get install vim".split(), stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
# Popen only accepts byte-arrays so you must encode the string
output = proc.communicate(password.encode())
stdoutput = (output)[0].decode('utf-8')
```

Output:

```
Installing Vim...|Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  vim-runtime
Suggested packages:
  ctags vim-doc vim-scripts
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  vim vim-runtime
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 7,111 kB of archives.
After this operation, 34.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
```

As you can see, the installation of the package stops and the `Do you want to continue?`, in which, for some reason, the installation is aborted.

**How do I pass in a `y` at this stage using `Popen()`?**

I am already passing in the password using `communicate()` but that is not taking **multiple inputs**.

Comment: You can pass a newline-delimitted string of multiple responses to `communicate`. You can also write directly to `proc.stdin` as needed.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to writing scrips using python, would you mind letting my know what exactly i would need to type, sorry for that :  )

Comment: If all you want to do is type `y` at every prompt, just pass the `-y` option to `apt-get` so that it doesn't prompt you in the first place. Otherwise, you are going to have to be more specific about what responses you actually want to make.

Comment: Also, I would consider running the script itself as root, so that it doesn't need to use `sudo` at all.

Comment: Do you mean this? ```proc = Popen("sudo -S -y apt-get install vim".split(), stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)```

Comment: When I run it with the -y , my ```stdoutput``` is empty and the installation fails again, any way to know why it is failing?

Comment: `-y` is not a `sudo` option; it's an `apt-get` option.

Comment: Yes, that fixed it, thanks so much, i've been struggling with this for a long time! Post this as an answer and i will upvote!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass `-y` as an option to `apt-get` to avoid the need to interact (further) with it.

```
proc = Popen(["sudo", "-S", "apt-get", "-y", "install", "vim"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
output, error = proc.communicate(password.encode())
stdoutput = output.decode('utf-8')
```